# ValueError: Comparing labels between series and dataframe in pandas (identically labeled error)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains an ID and a Value, and I', cycling through timestamps of that and I need to use that ID to retrieve a value corresponding to the same ID from another dataset. Here's some code:

```
patient_weight = float(weigth[(weigth['PatientID'] == otherDataframe['PatientID'])]['Value'])
```

I even tried to to the following:

```
PatientID=valuesDataset['PatientID']

patient_weight = float(weigth[(weigth['PatientID'] == PatientID)]['Value'])
```

Now, everytime I run the code I got the

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

errore right in this part. That is maybe because I'm evaluating a dataframe and a Series, but I don't know how to solve this. Is there a solution?

Full function code:

```
Dates = dataset['Date']
for Date in Dates:

    for index in range(1, len(valuesDataset)):
        if valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Date'] >= Date and valuesDataset.iloc[index - 1]['Date'] <= Date:
            found = 1
            # print(valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Date'],valuesDataset.iloc[index-1]['Date'])
            delta_minutes = float(((valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Date'] - valuesDataset.iloc[index - 1]['Date']).seconds) / 60)
            patient_weight = float(weigth[(weigth['PatientID'] == PatientID)]['Value'])

            break

    if found: vis = operations...

    found = 0
```

I fixed it by doing the merge operation like this:

```
found = 0
Dates = generalDataset['Date']
for Date in Dates:
    for index in range(1, len(valuesDataset)):
        if valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Date'] >= Date and adrData.iloc[index - 1]['Date'] <= Date:

            found = 1

            delta_minutes = float(((valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Date'] - valuesDataset.iloc[index - 1]['Date']).seconds) / 60)
            dose_mcg = (valuesDataset.iloc[index]['Value'] * 1000)
            res_weigth = pd.merge(generalDataset, valuesDataset, how='outer', left_on=['PatientID'], right_on=['PatientID'])
            # valuex = weigth, valuey = value 
            patient_weight = (res_weigth[(res_weigth['PatientID'] == PatientID)]['Value_x'])
            dose_mcg_kg_min = (dose_mcg / (patient_weight * delta_minutes))
            break

    if found: vis = vis + dose_mcg_kg_min * 100

for index in range(i, len(valuesDataset2)...
same as before
    if found: vis = vis + dose_mcg_kg_min * 100

for index in range(i, len(valuesDataset3)...
same as before
    if found: vis = vis + dose_mcg_kg_min * 100

for index in range(i, len(valuesDataset4)...
same as before
    if found: vis = vis + dose_mcg_kg_min * 100

    print(vis)
```

Now, this seems correct, but my values are extremely high and I would like to order them by PatientID and the values as floats between 0 and 7.0. My results are:

```
0      15733.202257
1      15733.202257
2      15733.202257
3      15733.202257
4      15733.202257
5      15733.202257
6      16362.530347
```

I can't understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: can you please paste samples for the datasets and expected output?

Comment: PatientID is a simple column with only IDs coming from otherDataframe, and it is considered a Series. While weigth has a column with IDs, and for each ID I have a column with a weigth (float). My result is the weigth for each of the IDs in the PatientID series, by comparing the ID from PatientID=otherDataframe['PatientID'] and weigth['PatientID']

Comment: here's a screenshot with both datasets with some censorship: https://imgur.com/a/B1lUaoq

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to add the weight of each patient in otherDataframe ?

Comment: I want to allocate in the variable patient_weigth the weigth, taken from dataset weigth, for each patient where the patientID is in valuesDataset I'm cycling. So, I do that by comparing the ID in the other valuesDataset and the ID in the weigth dataset